# Impressão de frases pré-definidas, de modo aleatório em C

Tags: c, array, string, tipagem, random

Olá, **sou iniciante em programação** e estou aprendendo a programar em C.
Quero fazer um programa que tenha algumas **frases já definidas.** Ex c/ vetores: `char vet1[100] = {"Hello World!"}; char vet2[100] = {"segunda frase"}; ...` **e a cada execução, retornar uma frase diferente na tela do usuário**.
O mais próximo que cheguei foi pensar em usar o `enum` em conjunto com `rand();`, porém não dá certo pois ele retorna apenas uma constante com valor decimal. 
Acho que a solução envolveria o uso de vários `vetores ou uma matriz de strings`, mas não sei se é isso mesmo.

Alguém sabe me passar uma ideia? 
Desde que seja de fácil entendimento para um iniciante.

*Já aprendi conteúdos básicos, e também vetores, matrizes, funções, ponteiros, alocação dinâmica e arquivos.*

**OBS: Não é necessário passar o código inteiro, basta apenas me explicar qual é a melhor solução para a implementação da parte das frases.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, como já tens a noção de vetor, sabes que colocar vários vetores de caracteres(strings) é cansativo. Então aconselho usar uma matriz:

```
int main()
{
    char minhas_palavras[10][100];
    return 0;
}
```

Com isso consigo armazenar 10 palavras de no máximo com 100 caracteres cada uma. Tem uma maneira mais eficiente, através de ponteiros e alocação dinâmica de memória, mas para este problema não precisamos disso.

Para receber números aleatórios, podes usar a função rand() da biblioteca  e então jogar o primeiro indice da matriz. Por exemplo:

```
int main()
{
    const int QUANTIDADE_PALAVRAS = 10;
    char minhas_palavras[QUANTIDADE_PALAVRAS][100];
    int numero_aleatorio;
    /* Aqui voce define suas palavras */
    numero_aleatorio = rand() % QUANTIDADE_PALAVRAS;
    printf("Palavra escolhida: %s", minhas_palavras[numero_aleatorio]);
    return 0;
}
```

Onde utilizamos uma constante chamada QUANTIDADE_PALAVRAS que indica que, neste caso, o valor máximo é 10 e não varia.

Caso você queira utilizar ponteiros e ter uma melhor aproveitamento de memória para não deixar 87 caracteres vazios no caso de "Hello World!". Assim, o código abaixo exemplifica essa ideia:

```
void grava_palavra(char *str, const char *palavra);
/* Pega todos os caracteres de *palavra e grava em *str
   assim como feito pela função strcopy */
char *aloca_memoria(int quantidade);
/* Essa funcao recebe um inteiro como argumento e retorna
   um ponteiro para caracter que indica onde foi alocada a memoria*/
int main()
{
    char *palavra;
    int quantidade_carac_palavra;
    /* Aqui voce define o tamanho da sua palavra. Ex: 13
       Não se esqueca do caracter '\0' no final     */
    palavra = aloca_memoria(quantidade_carac_palavra);
    grava_palavra(palavra, "Hello World!");
    printf("%s", palavra);
    free(palavra);
    return 0;
}
```

Assim, de maneira semelhante funciona para  colocar números aleatórios e obter frases aleatórios.

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char *grava(const char *str)
{
    char *pont;
    int i, tamanho = 0;
    while(*(str+tamanho) != '\0') 
        tamanho++;
    pont = (char *)malloc((tamanho+1)*sizeof(char));
    for(i=0; i<tamanho+1; i++)
        *(pont+i) = *(str+i);
    return pont;
}
char **grava_matriz(int quantidade)
{
    return (char **) malloc(quantidade*sizeof(char*));
}

int main()
{
    char **mat;
    int ale, q = 2;
    mat = grava_matriz(q);
    *(mat) = grava("Hello");
    *(mat+1) = grava("hey");
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    ale = rand()%q;
    printf("%s\n", *(mat+ale));
    free(*(mat));
    free(*(mat+1));
    free(mat);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bacana! Entendi bem o 1º código passado, e assim usei a função `strcpy`para cada palavra de cada linha da matriz. Ex: `strcpy(minhas_palavras[0],"A vida e bela");
 strcpy(minhas_palavras[1],"Hello World!");`etc...

Comment: Já para o segundo trecho de código, em que você sugere o uso de ponteiros, mesmo com a sua explicação, ainda não entendi o uso das duas funções declaradas antes da função principal. Ainda assim, vejo que de acordo com o trecho de código apresentado, se eu quisesse usar várias palavras (matriz), isso deveria ser feito usando a função `malloc`, por exemplo, para alocar essas matrizes, certo?

Comment: `char *grava(const char *str){
         char *pont;
         int i, tamanho = 0;
         while(*(str+tamanho) != '\0'){
             tamanho++; }
         pont = (char *)malloc((tamanho+1)*sizeof(char));
         for(i=0; i<tamanho+1; i++){
             *(pont+i) = *(str+i);
         return pont;
    }

    char **grava_matriz(int quantidade){
        return (char **) malloc(quantidade*sizeof(char*));
    }

int main(){
    char **mat;
    int ale, q = 2;
    *(mat) = grava("Hello");
    *(mat+1) = grava("hey");
    ale = rand()%q;
    printf("%s\n", *(mat+ale));
}`

Comment: Você utiliza a mesma ideia do código, contudo, utilizar ponteiros. Sim, a parte de fazer alocação de memória é usando malloc(ou calloc). Acima tem duas funções, a "grava" que recebe uma string e aloca memória e já grava a string na memora alocada.

Na main tem um exemplo que recebe duas palavras e imprime na tela ou a palavra "hey" ou a palavra "Hello".

Copie e idente o código, tentei colocar como se fosse um código com identação mas não consegui.

Uma correção: O return da função grava é fora do for.

Comment: Uma correção:
1) O return da função grava é fora do for.
2) Depois da declaração de variaveis, tem-se "mat = grava_matriz(q);"
3) Libere memoria.
Faltaram caracteres para colocar

Comment: Opa, entendi um pouco mais agora.     É só uma pena que os meus conhecimentos em ponteiro ainda não estejam bem afinados, pois ainda assim, fiquei com dúvida sobre o que está acontecendo no trecho `while(*(str+tamanho) != '\0') ` e no trecho `for(i=0; i<tamanho+1; i++)
        *(pont+i) = *(str+i);`.  E uma última dúvida, para cada nova string criada, devo usar o comando `free(*(mat+n));` _n corresponde a num da linha da string_, para liberar cada string criada, uma a uma?

Comment: Vamos lá. Você entende vetores, então está a meio caminho andado para entender ponteiros. O que acontece quando você quer pegar determinado elemento do vetor? Você faz `vetor[1]` por exemplo. Mas e o que acontece se você fizer `*(vetor+1)`? Significa a mesma coisa neste caso. Um vetor pode ser entendido como um ponteiro, mas diferentemente do ponteiro, você não pode alterar o endereço do vetor, isto é, fazer `vetor1 = vetor2`. O compilador informará o erro pois você está trabalhando com vetor e não ponteiros.

Comment: Da mesma maneira acontece com ponteiros, na verdade tem-se uma dificuldade pois você não pode fazer `ponteiro[1]` para significar `*(ponteiro+1)`. Por isso, você pode interpretar `*(ponteiro+1)` como `ponteiro[1]`, mas são coisas diferentes para o computador. Agora quanto ao `while`, a variável tamanho inicia em 0 e vai incrementando até achar o caracter `'\0'`. Uma vez que ele acha, ele encerra o loop. Se for passado uma string vazia, isto é, `""`, tem-se que `*(str+0)` terá o valor de `'\0'` e portanto encerra. Esse while é só para medir o tamanho da palavra. Se for "amor", então tamanho = 4

Comment: Aí, uma vez que sabemos o tamanho da palavra, devemos copiar ela para outra. Se fossem vetores normais, poderiamos fazer simplesmente `pont[i] = str[i]`, mas como `pont` é um ponteiro e `str`é um ponteiro, então eu utilizo `*(pont+i) = *(str+i)` para copiar no lugar de `pont[i]`. Quanto à string criada, sempre é necessário liberar a memória com `free`, para saber mais sobre o `free` e outras funcoes de alocação dinâmica de memória, aconselho pesquisar pois é um assunto meio extenso para eu explicar aqui.

Comment: Blz, bem explicado! Normalmente, principalmente para iniciantes é difícil entender ponteiros, principalmente quando se tem um ponteiro apontando para outro ponteiro . Então, quanto ao `free(*(mat));`
    e `free(*(mat+1));` notei que está sendo feita a liberação de memória de ponteiros, um a um, para cada palavra criada. Como vou ter muitas palavras, umas 30 eu acho, é possível liberar todas usando um for? Nunca treinei ponteiros de ponteiros ainda mas acho que é assim: `int i, aux;` `for (i = 0,aux = 0; i <= q; i++,aux++){
        free(*(mat+aux));
    }` Certo?  E por último `free(mat);`

Comment: Sim, isso aí. Podes utilizar o for para liberar uma grande quantidade. E só um detalhe, a sua condição de parada(`i <= q`) está errada, na verdade é `(i < q)` pois `*(mat+q)` não está definido

Comment: Ok. Muito obrigado pela paciência e atenção em me ajudar.